# When i try to get the array content I get "Array" instead of content

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

When I try to get the array content I get "Array" instead of content.

The foreach function (if it's right, I couldn't try it until now) should then post the pictures.

```
<?php
    $slideshowdir = "./public/all/slideshow/";
    if (is_dir($slideshowdir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($slideshowdir)) {                             
            while (($slides = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
               $possible_slides = $slideshowdir.array($slides);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($possible_slides as $slide){
        $picture = file($slide);
            echo $picture;
     }
?>
```

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't 100% clear. The files I want to post are pictures.

EDIT: I solved the problem with the following code:

```
<?php
    $possible_slides = array();
    $slideshowdir = "./public/all/slideshow/";
    if (is_dir($slideshowdir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($slideshowdir)) {                             
            while (($slide = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if (is_file ($slideshowdir.$slide)) {
                    $possible_slides[] = $slideshowdir.$slide;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($possible_slides as $slide){
        echo '<img src="'.$slide.'">';
    }       
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation for [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). It returns an array of a file's contents, line by line.

What you might want to use instead is [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Also, your first loop looks fishy. I suppose you want to do this:

```
<?php
$possible_slides = array();
$slideshowdir = "./public/all/slideshow/";
if (is_dir($slideshowdir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($slideshowdir)) {                             
        while (($slide = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
           if (is_file ($slideshowdir.$slide)) {
               $possible_slides[] = $slideshowdir.$slide;
           }
        }
    }
}

foreach($possible_slides as $slide){
    $picture = file_get_contents($slide);
    echo $picture;
}
```

Please note that I have added a check in the while loop to make sure only files are added to `$possible_slides`. This should filter out sub-directories, as well as `.` and `..`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that... But my problem is still alive, I always get the path/Array instead of path/slide1.jpg etc.

Comment: @Perocat Sorry, I didn't see the first one. I have edited my post to address both problems.

Comment: Thank you again! Unfortunately this is the result with file_get_contents: �����etc etc
And with file: ArrayArrayArray etc.

Comment: @Perocat I just tested the script and it works. What are the contents of the files you want to output? Some binary data?

Comment: Wait! Are the files actually pictures? (And not textfiles containing the names of pictures or similar?) If they are indeed pictures, please explain again what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes they are picture! Sorry...
I want to put all the picture of the slideshowdir into an array, and the echo the picture one after the other on the website.

Comment: I solved the problem with the code I posted on my original question. May I ask you why you have to define that $possible_slides is an array at the beginning, why you replaced the while (($slides with while (($slide and why the solution $possible_slides = $slideshowdir.array($slides) is not working well??
Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

This part seems hinky: `$slideshowdir.array($slides)`

Are you sure you want to concatenate an array onto a string?

Comment: I'd like to put all the slides on that folder onto an array and than echo all the pictures on the array

Comment: In that case, check out [array_push](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), and [implode](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). I think you will find that combination more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$possible_slides = $slideshowdir.array($slides);
```

To:

```
$possible_slides[] = $slideshowdir.array($slides);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply... I alway get Array Array Array etc.

Comment: What `var_dump($slide);` gives you back?